# Using struct in C# as you would in C - can you?

Tags: c#, c, binaryfiles, struct

I am reading a binary file of a specific format, and am used to being able to cast a block of data to a struct then reading the struct to pull fields out of the binary datafile.

I'm trying to do this but failing in C#, they seem more like classes than structures in the C sense.  Is it possible to do what I want?  For example..

```
public struct Datum {
    byte type;
    ushort payload;
}

public struct DiskPage {
    ushort pageNumber;
    Datum[] data = Datum[170];
}
```

I want to be able to read 512 bytes of a file and cast it to a DiskPage, then to be able to read the values from the DiskPage structure.  Is this possible in c#  - or is there another preferred approach?  Should I just leave that code in C and link it in?

Thanks!
Reza

Comment: I believe to do this exactly the way you're used to, this would require some sort of type punning, and in C# that would be unsafe code.  You'd have to use pointers rather than references (if it is even possible at all).

Comment: forget what you know of C and learn C# the C# way

Comment: It's possible - probably not a good idea. See Christopher Currens' answer on this StackOverflow question for how-to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030150/copying-byte-array-to-various-fields-in-class-struct-in-c/7030285#7030285

Comment: @David: good advice but there are still plenty of files and APIs with byte/bit layout around.

Comment: I've redefined my structs and code to access it here: http://pastebin.com/3bKkW2mB

Comment: I've redefined my structs and code to access it here: http://pastebin.com/3bKkW2mB

However, the code gets to the call PtrToStructure() and then it returns without doing anything and it doesn't seem to throw an error.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read [Mastering C# structs](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) that discusses using marshaling (`Marshal.Copy` in particular) for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks! that was a great link and the code from that was also identical to code I found here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fastbinaryfileinput.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't respect ordering of your fields by default (also it might move the fields and leave gaps in the memory = [Packing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx)). By using [StructLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) you can enforce a different behavior (Default, Sequential, or Explicit).

Use [MarshalAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) for specific options on a field. Be careful with endianess.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MySystemTime 
{
   [FieldOffset(0)]public ushort wYear; 
   [FieldOffset(2)]public ushort wMonth;
   [FieldOffset(4)]public ushort wDayOfWeek; 
   [FieldOffset(6)]public ushort wDay; 
   [FieldOffset(8)]public ushort wHour; 
   [FieldOffset(10)]public ushort wMinute; 
   [FieldOffset(12)]public ushort wSecond; 
   [FieldOffset(14)]public ushort wMilliseconds; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed arrays in C# if you compile with Unsafe option enabled.
You can also use pointers.

```
internal unsafe struct MyStruct
{
    public fixed byte MyFixedArray[128];
    public byte* MyPointer;
}
```

It is preferred to use marshalling, field offset and avoid unsafe code.
Use unsafe code if you really need too in small portion of your code.
Don't expose to external world a fixed array or a pointer (interfaces or public classes\structs) if you can avoid it.