# How to create a 2d array using information in a struct C#

Tags: c#, struct, multidimensional-array

Is there any way I can create a 2d array using the variables in the below struct please ?

```
public struct Marks
{
    public int midyearly;
    public int finalyear;
    public Marks(int midyearly, int finalyear)
    {
        this.midyearly = midyearly;
        this.finalyear = finalyear;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + midyearly + "," + finalyear + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you considered? `new [] { m.midyearly, m.finalyear }`?

Comment: Do you mean an array[] of marks ? or array[][] of marks ?

Comment: a 2d array that contains what?

Comment: If you are considering serialization, a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3278827/590790

Comment: Or another option - a matrix e.g. Marks[,].

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Marks[]` then you can create a 2D array like this:

```
Marks[] marks = ...;
var items = marks.Select(mark => new[] {mark.midyearly, mark.finalyear});
```

This will give you an `int[][]`.

But it's hard to tell if that's what you want.