# Struct for binary message serializiation/deserialization

Tags: c#, binary

I'm new to binary in C# and have a question on the best way to do this. I have an application I'm trying to communicate that has a specific binary message format. It has to begin with a `B8` hex code, and end with a `BB` hex code, with the binary message in between. What is the best way of being able to take a byte buffer and cast it to the message for easy access to the message properties? I'd imagine a struct, but in all honesty i don't really know.

EDIT:

The reason i don't want it in binary is so that I can easliy use the data in my application. For example, i'd like to convert the binary bits that represent a command type to an enum. Like this (just a representation of what I'd like to do):

```
struct CommandMessage
{
    public CommandType Command { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

enum CommandType
{
    UserJoined,
    MessageReceived
}
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Can you post an example of what you are trying to do? Why do you need this binary message? What do you do with it? Why do you want a C# representation that isn't a `byte[]`?

Comment: To answer that, we would need to understand exactly how the message is laid out in the byte[] - i.e. *can* it be logically unpacked as a struct (which frankly I don't really recommend anyway). In particular, any `string` content is going to mean "no". You also need to understand the endianness of any data, etc. Also : in binary there is nothing magic about `BB` / `B8` - what do you intend to do if a `BB` or `B8` happens naturally inside a float / int / string / guid / etc?

Comment: The example does nothing to explain the "specific binary message format", nor to explain what you're doing about the BB/B8 issue. Is the "specific binary message format" already defined? or are you free to choose your own layout?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278827/how-to-convert-a-structure-to-a-byte-array-in-c

Comment: K; it is already defined, but you haven't told us what that definition is. So how can we say whether you can map it directly to a struct, or advise on the best route forward? The details really matter here.

Comment: Sorry. `B8` precedes the command type, while `BB` follows the command and precedes the data. Then a `B8` closes the message

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [`protobuf-net`](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for `DTO` serialization.

So, define some entity e.g `Package` (`CommandMessage` in your sample) which has

```
public Command Command;
```

`public byte[] Data;` (serialized with `protobuf`)

Based on `Command` you will be able to deserialize `Data` to concrete `DTO` type using `protobuf`.

If your message should start with special prefix, you can handle this in `Package` as well.
Also, `Package` should handle writing/reading itself to/from binary stream or buffers (that's pretty strait forward).

e.g `package.WriteTo(buffer)` produces `[BB,Command,Data,B8]`. Same for `package.ReadFrom()`

Comment: @MarcGravell as far as I understood from comments, it should work. Let me explain: DTOs are serialized with protobuf, but Package (wrapper around DTO+Command) handles all the read/write logic. So say we have package.WriteTo(...) which writes [BB, Command, Data(serialized DTO), B8]. Same approach for reading.

Comment: until you get a naturally occurring B8 in the payload