# C# Generic read/write methods for Buffer

Tags: c#, templates, generics, buffer

I've been trying to write a Buffer class that lets me write to and read from an internal List buffer using generic methods. In C++ it was no problem, since we have nice access to the memory directly (memcpy (I know memcpy is unsafe) and so on).

I have tried the following:

```
// private readonly List<byte> _buffer = new List<byte>();
public void Write<T>(T value) where T : byte, short, ushort, int, uint {
    _buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));
}
```

... But it says, that the best overload has some invalid arguments (value).

I also have problems reading a value of the type byte, short, ushort, int or uint. I could surely determine the type of T and then use the BitConverter class to convert the bytes but i'm sure there is a more easy and DRY way to do this (which I haven't discovered yet).

How to implement such methods to keep the class sweet and simple?

**EDIT:**

To read from the buffer I've tried the following:

```
public T Read<T>(bool moveIndex = true) {
    T data = default(T);
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(data);
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, data);
    Marshal.Copy(_buffer.ToArray(), _readIndex, ptr, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    if (moveIndex) {
        _readIndex += size;
    }
    return data;
}
```

But it throws me a System.ArgumentException in this line *Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, data);*

Comment: I'm afraid the generic approach probably won't be possible in C#. C++ templates and C# generics just don't work in the same way! This approach should work for you though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3278908/2609288

Comment: Hi @Baldrick, your link doesn't help me that much, as I want to write simple datatypes like int or short to the buffer, not a structure.

Comment: Make an array of length 1, then use `Buffer.BlockCopy`?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suit your needs?

```
public void Write<T>(T value) where T: struct
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(value);
    var bytes = new byte[size];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(value, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    _buffer.AddRange(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kyle, your code works for me. I tried to do the same for reading from that buffer but how do I figure out the size of type T? Marshal.SizeOf() expects a variable, not a type.