# Error on StuctureToPtr

Tags: c#, struct, binaryfiles

I have a binary files that were made with `structs`. I'm getting this error when trying to write a `struct` back to the binary file: `Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout.`

Here's the `struct`, which should be `2368 bytes`. Confirmed this by doing `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DATA))` and basic math.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DATA
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] GD;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Label; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Feat;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Wor;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Source; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Anam;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Crete;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Miss;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Best;         
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] Xware;    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] XVersion;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] UncertX;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] UncertY;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    public char[] Descrip;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    public char[] Discrim; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1024)]
    public char[] Reserved;
}
```

I made a simple `char[]` to test:

```
char[] testArray = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
DATA testStruct = new DATA(); //declare the struct
testStruct.Miss = testArray; //set one of the fields to the char[]
```

Then I write to the binary file:

```
using (var fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append))
{
    WriteRampToFile(gisDA, fStream );
}

/// <summary>
/// Writes byte array containing a given struct to a file
/// </summary>
public void WriteRampToFile<T>(T str, FileStream fStream )
{
    byte[] buffer = GetBytes(str); //puts struct into byte array
    fStream .Write(buffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))); //write byte     array to file
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the given struct and returns it as a byte array
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">A structure defined at the top of this file</param>
public byte[] GetBytes<T>(T str)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
    byte[] arr = new byte[size];
    GCHandle h = default(GCHandle);

    try
    {
        h = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, h.AddrOfPinnedObject(), false); //Error     here
    }
    finally
    {
        if (h.IsAllocated)
        {
            h.Free();
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare the array with size 64 and fill it with 4?
And have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278827/how-to-convert-a-structure-to-a-byte-array-in-c

Comment: It is not a very appropriate way to accomplish this.  Note the glaring bug in WriteRampToFile(), it is generic on T but you use typeof(GISDATA).  What is GISDATA??  Your code corrupts the GC heap and anything can happen next.  The exception is raised because the pinvoke marshaller sees a mismatch between the size of one the char[] elements and the SizeConst value.  You'll have to slog the code and ensure they *all* are an exact match.  That largely defeats the point of using Marshal.StructureToPtr(), you might as well use BinaryWriter.

Comment: Sorry that was a remnant from older code I forgot to change. Fixed it. What would be an appropriate way to go about it? I can make the array size match like you guys said and make it work, but I want to do it the right way.

Comment: You're aware that `char` is two bytes? I'm not sure that the `Ansi` flag is going to save you. You might try switching to byte arrays and using the ANSII encoding to convert your values to bytes before sending.