# How to implement a struct that solely contains predefined contents but can still be Marshal'd?

Tags: c#

(The question title has been updated to reflect that the struct must eventually be converted using the Marshal class.)

I have some structs that by design will always contain fixed values.  For example, let's assume a struct that contains two bytes:

```
public struct ExampleStruct {
    public byte b0;
    public byte b1;
}
```

How can I update that implementation so that `b0` always holds the value `0` and `b1` always holds the value `1`?  I've tried various combinations of `const`, `readonly`, and constructors, all with no luck.

Ideally I'll be able to use it like this and have the bytes initialized to the correct values:

```
ExampleStruct es = new ExampleStruct();
```

Note that I eventually need to convert the struct to a `byte[]` using the `Marshal` class so it can be sent to a driver.  I have verified that this prohibits the use of properties within the struct, as those properties are ignored during the Marshal to `byte[]`.  Also note that in this case Marshal != Serialize, as I need the actual struct byte contents and not a serialized string that can be deserialized later.

Comment: For a struct, it may be zero-initialized, and that's unavoidable. You can use properties though, and avoid fields altogether: `public byte b0 => 0; public byte b1 => 3;`

Comment: For serialization properties usually work better than fields, so maybe properties *are* the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with structs is that you cannot ensure that they will be initialized. If a struct is a class field, then it will be nulled when the containing object is created. It is then perfectly legal to access its fields and properties without first calling `new`.

You can use getter-only (i.e., read-only) properties instead:

```
public struct ExampleStruct
{
    public byte B0 => 0;
    public byte B1 => 1;
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
public struct ExampleStruct
{
    public byte B0 { get { return 0; } }
    public byte B1 { get { return 1; } }
}
```

Another option is to declare constants:

```
public struct ExampleStruct
{
    public const byte B0 = 0, B1 = 1;
}
```

however, here you must access the constants through the type name, since constants are static.

```
var x = ExampleStruct.B1;
```

---

Answer to updated question:

You can use a static factory method or property to initialize the struct:

```
public struct ExampleStruct
{
    private byte _b0;
    private byte _b1;

    public byte B0 { get => _b0;  }
    public byte B1 { get => _b1; }

    public static ExampleStruct ZeroOne => new ExampleStruct { _b0 = 0, _b1 = 1 };
}
```

You can create a value with:

```
ExampleStruct es = ExampleStruct.ZeroOne;

// Test whether it can by marshalled to byte[]
byte[] bytes = GetBytes(es);
Console.WriteLine(bytes[0]); // --> 0
Console.WriteLine(bytes[1]); // --> 1
```

Method used for this test:

```
// Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278956/880990, Vincent McNabb
static byte[] GetBytes(ExampleStruct es)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(es);
    byte[] arr = new byte[size];

    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(es, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}
```

This works. Note that the properties are only used to access the private fields, but it's the fields that are copied with the `Marshal` class.