Why do I get a higher pitched sound or artifacts when sliding between notes?
I'm building a system to create melodies using specific sound waves, I'm using C# and writing into WAV files. The process is creating a melody as an array of frequencies, which indicates the frequency of the sound at one point in time. A sound is simply defined as a function to be sampled at a point in time. The final sound is created by tuning this sound to the frequency defined by the melody at each point and sampling that to generate a final array of offsets to generate the sound. I'm using notes in 12-tet 440hz and calculating their frequencies.
Here's the problem: I want the melody to support sliding between two different notes, so I can for example, say, in the next 5 seconds slide from C3 to G3, as in add the frequencies that run from the frequency of C3 to the frequency of G3. But this doesn't work as I'd expect, some times there's some sort of artifact while doing the sliding, a lot of the times the sound is pitched much higher up than I expected, suddenly sounding completely different from what I expected.
To be more specific about the sliding, I've tried before to simply do a linear interpolation between the two frequencies but as of right now, the sliding is in a curve that makes it so that each note in between the frequencies gets an even amount of time. This is of course not linear. Either way you choose to face this problem in my code, the problem I described remains.
The melody class generates a melody by adding "lines", which is defining a period of time, where you want to start (frequency) and where you want to end. Here I leave a working example, to compile it you need .NET. I suspect there's easier ways to run this, but you can run "dotnet new console" on an empty folder, and then paste this entire code into the main file and then run "dotnet run" on the terminal. You'll have test.wav as an output. The intention is to play G3 for 1 second, then slide from G3 to G4 for 5 seconds, then stay in G4 for 1 second and finally go down to C3.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Melody
    {
        public Melody()
        {
            _pitch = new List<double>();
        }

        private const int sample_amount = 44100;

        public void AddLine(double duration, double start, double end)
        {
            int spaceToFill = (int) Math.Floor(duration * sample_amount);
            CurrentSecond = CurrentSecond += spaceToFill / sample_amount;
            
            double c = 2;
            double e = Math.Log(end / start) / Math.Log(c);

            for (int i = 0; i < spaceToFill; i++)
            {
                double t = ((double) i) / spaceToFill;
                double s = t * e;

                //_pitch.Add((1 - (i / 100.0)) * pitch_last + (i / 100.0) * point);
                _pitch.Add(start * Math.Pow(c, s));
            }
        }
        
        public double PitchAt(double second)
        {
            return _pitch[(int) Math.Floor(second * sample_amount)]; //Possibly bad
        }

        public int CurrentSecond { get; private set; }
        private List<double> _pitch;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum Note   
    {
        SHARP = 0b00000_0001,
        FLAT = 0b00000_0010,
        C = 0b00000_0100,
        D = 0b00000_1000,
        E = 0b00001_0000,
        F = 0b00010_0000,
        G = 0b00100_0000,
        A = 0b01000_0000,
        B = 0b10000_0000,
    }

    public static class Notes
    {
        static Notes()
        {
            _noteMap = new Dictionary<Note, int>();
            _noteMap.Add(Note.C, 0);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.C | Note.SHARP, 1);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.D | Note.FLAT, 1);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.D, 2);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.D | Note.SHARP, 3);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.E | Note.FLAT, 3);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.E, 4);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.E | Note.SHARP, 5);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.F | Note.FLAT, 4);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.F, 5);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.F | Note.SHARP, 6);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.G | Note.FLAT, 6);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.G, 7);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.G | Note.SHARP, 8);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.A | Note.FLAT, 8);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.A, 9);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.A | Note.SHARP, 10);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.B | Note.FLAT, 10);
            _noteMap.Add(Note.B, 11);
        }

        private const double NoteSeparation = 1.0594630943592952645618252949463417007792043174941856285592084314;

        private static int _MapNoteToIndex(Note note, int octave)
        {
            if (note == (Note.B | Note.SHARP)) return (octave + 1) * 12;
            if (note == (Note.C | Note.FLAT)) return (octave - 1) * 12;

            return octave * 12 + _noteMap[note];
        }

        public static double GetNoteFrequency(Note note, int octave)
        {
            double c0 = 16.352;
            return c0 * Math.Pow(NoteSeparation, _MapNoteToIndex(note, octave));
        }

        private static Dictionary<Note, int> _noteMap;
    }


    public static class Song
    {
        public static double[] GenerateWave(Melody melody, Sound sound)
        {
            double[] data = new double[44100 * melody.CurrentSecond];

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
            {
                double second = ((double) i) / 44100.0;
                data[i] = sound.Evaluate(second, melody.PitchAt(second));
            }

            return data;
        }

        public static double[] GenerateWave(List<Melody> melodies, Sound sound)
        {
            double[] data = new double[44100 * melodies[0].CurrentSecond];

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
            {
                data[i] = 0.0;
                double second = ((double) i) / 44100.0;

                foreach (Melody melody in melodies) 
                {
                    if (second < melody.CurrentSecond)
                        data[i] += sound.Evaluate(second, melody.PitchAt(second));
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
    }

public struct WAVHeader
{
    public Int32 ChunkID; 
    public Int32 ChunkSize;
    public Int32 Format;

    public Int32 Subchunk1ID;
    public Int32 Subchunk1Size;
    public Int16 AudioFormat;
    public Int16 NumChannels;
    public Int32 SampleRate;
    public Int32 ByteRate;
    public Int16 BlockAlign;
    public Int16 BitsPerSample;

    public Int32 Subchunk2ID;
    public Int32 Subchunk2Size;

    public static int size = sizeof(Int32) * 9 + sizeof(Int16) * 4;
}

    //We use double depth
    public static class WAVWriter
    {
        //http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/
        public static WAVHeader StandardHeader(int samples)
        {
            WAVHeader res;

            res.ChunkID = 0x46464952; //"RIFF" flip it
            res.Format = 0x45564157; //"WAVE"

            res.Subchunk1ID = 0x20746D66; //"fmt "
            res.Subchunk1Size = 16;
            res.AudioFormat = 1;
            res.NumChannels = 1; //Mono
            res.SampleRate = 44100; //Standard
            res.BitsPerSample = 16; //!16?
            res.ByteRate = res.SampleRate * res.NumChannels * res.BitsPerSample / 8;
            res.BlockAlign = Convert.ToInt16(res.NumChannels * res.BitsPerSample / 8);

            res.Subchunk2ID = 0x61746164; //"data"
            res.Subchunk2Size = samples * res.NumChannels * res.BitsPerSample / 8;

            res.ChunkSize = 4 + (8 + res.Subchunk1Size) + (8 + res.Subchunk2Size);

            return res;
        }

        public static void Write(string fileName, WAVHeader header, double[] data)
        {
            using (var file = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (var bWriter = new BinaryWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8, false))
                {
                    bWriter.Write(_getBytesHeader(header));

                    double maxx = 0.0;

                    foreach (double i in data)
                    {
                        if (maxx < Math.Abs(i)) maxx = Math.Abs(i);
                    }

                    foreach (double i in data)
                    {
                        bWriter.Write((short) ((i / maxx) * 32766 / 2));
                    }

                    //bWriter.Write(_getBytesFloat(data));
                }
            }
        }

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278827/how-to-convert-a-structure-to-a-byte-array-in-c
        private static byte[] _getBytesHeader(WAVHeader str) {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
            byte[] arr = new byte[size];

            IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
                Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
            }

            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            }

            return arr;
        }

        private static byte[] _getBytesFloat(double[] data) {
            int size = sizeof(double) * data.Count();
            byte[] arr = new byte[size];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, arr, 0, size);

            return arr;
        }
    }

    public class Sound
    {
        public Sound(List<Func<double,double>> generators)
        {
            _generators = new List<Func<double,double>>(generators);
        }

        public double Evaluate(double second, double pitch)
        {
            double accumulated = 0.0;

            foreach (var f in _generators)
                accumulated += f((second / 440.0) * pitch);

            return accumulated;
        }   

        private List<Func<double,double>> _generators;
    }

    internal class Program
    {

        public static double F(double x, double t)
        {
            //return 2.0 * Math.Pow(((Math.Sin(x) + 1.0) / (2.0)), Math.Max(0.1, 5.0 - t * 0.5)) - 1;
            return Math.Sin(x);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Melody melody = new Melody();
            melody.AddLine(1, Notes.GetNoteFrequency(Note.G, 3), Notes.GetNoteFrequency(Note.G, 3));
            melody.AddLine(5, Notes.GetNoteFrequency(Note.G, 3), Notes.GetNoteFrequency(Note.G, 4));
            melody.AddLine(1, Notes.GetNoteFrequency(Note.G, 4), Notes.GetNoteFrequency(Note.G, 4));
            melody.AddLine(1, Notes.GetNoteFrequency(Note.C, 3), Notes.GetNoteFrequency(Note.C, 3));
            
            var generators = new List<Func<double,double>>();
            generators.Add(t => (Math.Sin(t * 2.0 * Math.PI * 440.0) + Math.Sin(t * 2.0 * Math.PI * 880.0) * 0.05 + Math.Sin(t * 2.0 * Math.PI * 440.0 * 3) * 0.025 + Math.Sin(t * 2.0 * Math.PI * 440.0 * 4) * 0.001));

            Sound sound = new Sound(generators);

            List<Melody> melodies = new List<Melody>();
            melodies.Add(melody);

            WAVWriter.Write("test.wav", WAVWriter.StandardHeader(44100 * melody.CurrentSecond), Song.GenerateWave(melody, sound));
        }
    }
}


Pitching discrete audio is not as easy as you think. Even the simplest approach, which involves stretching time, still requires resampling. You cannot resample at a single point, or you will introduce other frequencies to your signal that are heard as artifacts or distortion. Basically, any errors in sampling become audible as sound. Look up sinc filtering if you want to resample audio more cleanly. If you want to pitch without stretching time, the problem becomes very hard and requires transformation into the frequency domain, then recombining while properly tracking phase.

So you are tracking frequencies, generating waveforms based on sine waves, then adding the samples together? You can't just glue chunks of sine waves with different frequencies together, any discontinuity in the curve will be audible. You need a different function that can generate a continuous curve, with more complex input parameters. (maybe https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63813/how-can-i-generate-a-sine-wave-with-time-varying-frequency-that-is-continuous-i ?)

Oh I didn't know there was a Signal Processing community in Stack Exchange! a lesson I can learn from both these responses is I should deepend my understanding of Signal Processing before trying to tackle this more, as I can't really understand sinc filtering articles, and that this is much harder to do than I thought indeed. @JeremyLakeman as for the link you provided, it looks like something useful for other audio artifacts I get, it's not exactly what I'm looking for sliding smoothly, linearly between two notes.

Yeah that was just the first result for a sine wave with discontinuities... you'll have to pick your own function. Perhaps involving splines for how you want the frequency to vary over time, then ... no idea. Probably some calculus / polynomial of some kind.

I wanted to ask, how I would look for information about this topic, is it with the term signal processing? part of the reason why my solutions are so patchwork is that when I tried to look information up, I'd get results about Digital Audio Workstations for example, not results relating to the computing of the actual waves

Include programming-related terms in your search, such as "algorithm". First, you need to decide whether you're trying to just play the audio at a different speed ("easy" - results in pitch-shifting and time-stretching) or if you're trying to pitch-shift without time-stretching (hard). I already pointed you in the right direction for the first one, and mentioned some of the challenges for the second one. I used to work for an audio software company that's famous for both of these things, and I have a fair idea of what I'm talking about.

By the way, I just typed pitch shift c# into an internet search engine and got loads of useful-looking results. I don't know how you use the internet, but that's what I'd do if I wanted to learn by example.
