# write struct data to binary file

Tags: c#

I received some data (many times) which are encapsulated inside a `struct`. what I need to do is write them to a file (binary) to restore the data. how will you do it?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628843/byte-for-byte-serialization-of-a-struct-in-c

Comment: Do you need to write it in a specific format (e.g. to be read by another program) or just so you can save some status and read it again from the same program? In the later case I would suggest declaring the struct [serializable] (and all custom member types) and just serialize it to the file.

Comment: I was going to Answer "Let me Google that for you" but I may get to many upvotes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement `ISerializable` (greater customization) or mark with the `[Serializable]` attribute (easier to use).  Then use a `BinaryFormatter` to serialize to a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
public struct MyStruct : ISerializable
    {
        #region ISerializable Members

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(MyStruct m1, MyStruct m2)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(MyStruct m1, MyStruct m2)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```