# Is serialization possible for a struct

Tags: c#, oop, serialization, struct

Can I serialize a `struct` type directly since its a value type.

I have used it inside class but wondering if its possible for a struct alone.

e.g.

```
struct student
{
   name string; --string is a reference type
   age int;
   designation string; --string is a reference type
   salary double;
};

class foo
{
 foo(){
   student s;
   s.name = "example";

   serialize(s);
  }
}
```

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b479edea-cc9e-4755-9ef4-d54ece298306/can-a-struct-implement-iserializable-how-do-you-serialize-a-structs-private-members?forum=csharpgeneral) link says
*"I tried having my struct implement ISerializable, but I can't implement the required constructor because this is a struct and not an object."*

Comment: it is possible, just follo the instruction on this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628843/byte-for-byte-serialization-of-a-struct-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Zalomon: There is no accepted answer on this link even. Looking at the link, it seems developer has to write its own code somehow. But not possible directly

Comment: Just because an answer is not accepted doesnt mean it doesnt work; it may just mean the OP couldnt be bothered to click the check.  It has 7 upvotes, so there is *some* value to it.  Try it.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta So not only do you refuse to even *try* to solve the problem yourself, you refuse to even *consider* the answer that you've been given?  I guess you just have no interest in actually solving the problem.

Comment: My purpose is not to achieve serialization only. But to understand why how its serializing being a value type. Moreover I don't see given method is portable across different languages. If I am saving serialized object in db and trying to deserialize from another language. There is no contract defined. Also, in given solution developer has hardcoded position of each byte from where it will start.

Comment: So why does any of that mean that require that you refuse to even try to solve the problem yourself to see what happens, or what problems you have, and why does it require you to refuse to even look at any other answers that are posted to see if they work for you?  If you've attempted to do this, run into problems, done research on how to solve those problems, not had them resolve your problem, and explained all of that in your question, then you'd actually have a real question.

Comment: You may like to read my previous comment which clearly states why I think OP might not have accepted answer as well. I see highest vote answer to be possible work around. If you have any link that explains why that's the only way to serialize a struct by hard coding position of each property. I will be more than happy to understand it.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can. I just did so with the following code.

```
[Serializable]
public struct TestStruct
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public double Value4 { get; set; }
}

TestStruct s1 = new TestStruct();
s1.Value1 = 43265;
s1.Value2 = 2346;
s1.Value3 = "SE";

string serialized = jss.Serialize(s1);
s2 = jss.Deserialize<TestStruct>(serialized);
Console.WriteLine(serialized);
Console.WriteLine(s2.Value1 + " " + s2.Value2 + " " + s2.Value3 + " " + s2.Value4);
```

What did it do? Exactly what it should have, **serialized** and **deserialized** the `struct`.

Output:

```
{"Value1":43265,"Value2":2346,"Value3":"SE","Value4":5235.3}
43265 2346 SE 5235.3
```

Funny, that's the `TestStruct` **serialized** and **deserialized** to/from `JSON`.

What about a **default constructor**? **All** `struct` objects have a default constructor, it's one of the *fundamental properties* of a `struct` object, and that default constructor is merely responsible for clearing the memory required for a `struct` object to the default values. Therefore, the `serializer` *already knows* there is a default constructor, and therefore can proceed as if it's a regular object (*which it is*).

### Notes:

This example uses `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`.

This example assumes all the variables inside the `struct` are **properties.** If they are not, then this answer *may* not work. It seems to work for me with `fields` in place of the `properties`, but that's not a best-practice. You should always make sure that the `public` variables in all objects are `properties`.

Comment: I am wondering how come serialization is possible for value type as we cannot create an object i.e. reference of struct. Curious to know why it won't work without property.

Comment: Because `serialization` doesn't care. If `serialization` would not let us `serialize` value types, then we could not serialize *anything*, as at some point **all** objects rely on a value type. **ALL** `struct` objects have a `default constructor`, which **all** serializers (I have come across, at least) require. You **cannot** take that away. It's one of the *fundamental properties* of a `struct` object. They should be valid *even* if all the memory they contain is *zeroed out*.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta I just ran it with those `properties` acting as `fields` and it ran successfully. The main requirements for `serialization` are that the variables be `public`, have an accessor/`getter`, and have a mutator/`setter`.

Comment: CS0103: The name `Serializable` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Meant is XML serializing and that don't work!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'll make it easier for your, this is how I did it

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class IClockFingerprintTemplate
{
    public ushort Size;
    public ushort PIN;
    public byte FingerID;
    public byte Valid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public byte[] Template;
}

    protected static byte[] RawSerialize(object item, Type anyType)
    {
        int structSize;
        byte[] bff;
        IntPtr ptr;

        structSize = ((IClockFingerprintTemplate)item).Size; 
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(item, ptr, true);
        bff = new byte[structSize];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bff, 0, 6);
        Array.Copy(((IClockFingerprintTemplate)item).Template, 0, bff, 6, structSize - 6);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
```

Comment: You are using a class. I am thinking about value types i.e. struct specifically.

Comment: For strings you're gonna need a little more, such as

`code`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
        public byte[] Password = new byte[5];

Comment: This means there is always a chance of loosing characters during serialization if length of string goes beyond input specified length in struct

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? `.NET` provides `XML`, `Binary` and `JSON` serializers built in.